# How to stop my processes from idling or being killed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I need to process millions of users. I have millions of user_ids, I fetch the user data from a http request and write to a file.

I am using multiprocessing to perform a batch of these task. I then use multithreading in each process to execute a task in a batch. This significantly improves the performance and enables to me to process more users at a faster rate.

**Problem**:

I find after a certain amount of time all the processes are becoming inactive. I know this by looking at the activity monitor. At the beginning i can see they use a lot of cpu and have threads, after a while they seem idle and my program hangs.

```py
import os
import time
import logging
import multiprocessing
import config
import json
from google.cloud import storage
from pymongo import MongoClient, UpdateOne
from queue import Queue
import threading
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

PROCESSES = multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1

def get_tweet_objects(user, counter, lock, proc):

   # Removed ( calls a http request and writes json file to disk

    lock.acquire()
      try:
        counter.value = counter.value + 1
      finally:
        lock.release()

    print("APP ID: {app_id}, REMAINING: {app_remaining}, TOTAL USERS: {total_users}, USER: {user_id}, NO OF TWEETS: {no_tweets}, TIME TAKEN: {time_taken}"
          .format(app_id=app.APP_ID, app_remaining=0, total_users=counter.value, user_id=user["user_id"], no_tweets=len(total_tweets), time_taken=round((end - start), 2)), threading.current_thread().name, proc)


def add_tasks(task_queue, tasks):

    for task in tasks:
        task_queue.put(task)

    return task_queue


def process_tasks(task_queue, counter, lock):

    logger = multiprocessing.get_logger()
    proc = os.getpid()
    while not task_queue.empty():
        try:
            user = task_queue.get()
            do_multithreading(user, counter, lock, proc)

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(e)
        logger.info(f'Process {proc} completed successfully')
    return True


def manage_queue(task_queue, counter, lock, proc):

    while True:
        user = task_queue.get()
        get_tweet_objects(user, counter, lock, proc)
        task_queue.task_done()


def do_multithreading(batches, counter, lock, proc):
    """Starts the multithreading"""

    # Set the number of threads.
    number_of_threads = 5

    # Initializes the queue.
    task_queue = Queue()

    # Starts the multithreading
    for i in range(number_of_threads):
        t = threading.Thread(target=manage_queue, args=[
                             task_queue, counter, lock, proc])
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    for batch in batches:
        task_queue.put(batch)
    task_queue.join()


def run():

    mongodb = MongoClient(host=config.MONGO_URI)["twitter"]

    existing_users = mongodb[SCREEN_NAME].find({}).limit(10000)

    batches = create_batches_of_100(existing_users)

    empty_task_queue = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()
    full_task_queue = add_tasks(empty_task_queue, batches)
    processes = []

    counter = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0)
    lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

    print(f'Running with {PROCESSES} processes!')
    start = time.time()
    for w in range(PROCESSES):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=process_tasks, args=(full_task_queue, counter, lock))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
    print(f'Time taken = {time.time() - start:.10f}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.log_to_stderr(logging.ERROR)
    run()
```

Comment: They are idle because you have a serious leak: your `manage_queue` never quits (even when the queue is empty) and you spawn 5 of them for each user. If you have 10000 users then it is likely that you run out of file descriptors. Even sooner if you touch http and files in each one of them. But you do log errors, doesn't your `process_tasks` function log them?

Comment: @freakish i was looking for those logs, it just hands on my last print statement in the get_tweet_objects function

Comment: Ok, so first of all refactor all of that code. Use [process/thread executors](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) instead of manually spawning them (you do it wrong). Then don't ever allow an infinite task like `manage_queue`. With executors you will be forced to do that anyway. I'm 99% sure that your issue is that you run out of descriptors and your logging doesn't work because... you run out of descriptors. XD You probably log to files, right? Then depending on the underlying logging implementation you may not see any result. Without file descriptors you are blind.

Comment: thanks i may have been following an old guide for multiprocessing.

https://testdriven.io/blog/developing-an-asynchronous-task-queue-in-python/ (edited)

Comment: The way the guide talks about is ok but is more difficult. You need to know stuff. Also perhaps I've emphasized executors too much. That's not the point. The problem is the infinite loop.

Comment: Oh cool the executors does queuing for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52478532/how-to-use-queue-in-concurrent-futures-processpoolexecutor

Maybe it will be better to refactor.

Comment: What is wrong wiht my manage_queue? should i wrap the code in a     `while not task_queue.empty():`?

Comment: That won't do, because you have a race condition anyway. The proper solution is to do `user = task_queue.get(False)` (so nonblocking get) and `break` on `Queue.Empty` exception. Also in `do_multithreading` you need to fill the queue **before** spawning threads. The function is broken as it is. Once the queue is empty it **hangs** on `.get()` **forever** eating your OS resources. And this leads to everything hanging, including logging (or at least this is what I believe).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192916/discussion-between-kay-and-freakish).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So there are multiple issues with the code. First of all avoid infinite loops at all costs like in `manage_queue` function. Note: I don't mean "avoid `while True:`", because it doesn't mean that it is an infinite loop (for example you can have `break` inside it).

With that being said the biggest problem (which we've discovered in long discussion in chat) is that `get_tweet_object()` function sometimes fails with an exception and when that happens `task_queue.task_done()` is never called and therefore `task_queue.join()` never exits.

Another issue is that mixing `while not task_queue.empty():` with `task_queue.get()` is a race condition. What happens when two parallel threads run and `task_queue` has exactly 1 element? One of them will hang forever. This should be replaced with `task_queue.get(False)` with appropriate `queue.Empty` catching. It looks like cosmetics, but the fact is that the race condition is dealt with in `.get()` call. With that you also need to fill the queue before spawning threads.

All in all here are changes:

```
from queue import Empty

def do_multithreading(batches, counter, lock, proc):
    """Starts the multithreading"""

    # Set the number of threads.
    number_of_threads = 5

    # Initializes the queue.
    for batch in batches:
        task_queue.put(batch)

    # Starts the multithreading
    for i in range(number_of_threads):
        t = threading.Thread(target=manage_queue, args=[
                             task_queue, counter, lock, proc])
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
    task_queue.join()

def manage_queue(task_queue, counter, lock, proc):
    while True:
        try:
            user = task_queue.get(False)
        except Empty:
            break

        try:
            get_tweet_objects(user, counter, lock, proc)
        except Exception as exc:
            print(exc)
        finally:
            task_queue.task_done()

def process_tasks(task_queue, counter, lock):
    logger = multiprocessing.get_logger()
    proc = os.getpid()
    while True:
        try:
            user = task_queue.get(False)
        except Empty:
            break
        try:
            do_multithreading(user, counter, lock, proc)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(e)
        logger.info(f'Process {proc} completed successfully')
    return True
```

With that being said I strongly advice utilizing [process/thread executors](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html).

Comment: You mentioned you strongly advise using executors, but how do you manage some state /multiple state that needs to be synchronised between processes using executors.

Comment: @Kay that depends on what exactly is the nature of this shared state. You can always define a simple class representing the state with thread/process safe getters and setters. And pass an instance of this class around.

Comment: yes this is what i am trying to do. Except its a list of classes that need to be synced not just one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56092001/how-to-share-a-synchronised-list-of-classes-between-processes-in-python-multipro